# How to check if a certain html fragment is already loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have the following code:

```
 $("#blogs").mouseover(
    function () {
      $(this).addClass("hover");

      $("#home").removeClass("hover");
      $("#homepages").removeClass("hover");
      $("#apps").removeClass("hover");
      $("#facebook").removeClass("hover");
      $("#kontakt").removeClass("hover");

      $("#content").hide().load("blogs.html", function(){
      $("#content").show("slide"); 

    });  
 });
```

Works all fine, but now I would like the load() / show() function only be called if #content does not already contain blogs.html.

In other words: I would like to check if blogs.html is already loaded and if yes, simply do nothing and only if not there yet I would load and show it.

Have tried some things with hasClass() and some if-formulas but struggle to get this check.

Tried stuff like this:

```
$("#content section").hasClass("check_blog").hide().load("blogs.html", function(){
$("#content").show("slide");
```

Basically I just need to know how I can check if blogs.html is already the contents of #content.

Thanks a lot for any help. Regards, Andi

Comment: It would help if you posted some code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: So does #content start out empty?

Comment: You can check if the element with id `content` has html in it using something like this `if($('#content').html() == '') {...`

Comment: have added something I tried in the question. Sorry I do not remember exaclly what I tried as I have already deleted it again as it did not work at all...

Comment: @wirey: no it starts with a content called home.html. I use this struction for kind of a mouseover/hover menu bar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ID to some element in blogs.html, say `blogsloaded`, then you can check for it with:

```
if (!$("#blogsloaded").length)
    $("#content").hide().load("blogs.html" ...
```

Another method would be to store in a variable if you already loaded it:

```
if (!this.blogsloaded)
{
    this.blogsloaded=true;
    $("#content").hide().load("blogs.html" ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split up your mouseover events into two namespaced events.  One which will only run once.

```
// This event will only run once
$("#blogs").on("mouseover.runonce", function () {
    $("#content").load("blogs.html");
});

// because this event will unbind the previous one
$("#blogs").on("mouseover.alwaysrun", function () {
    $(this).off("mouseover.runonce");

    $(this).addClass("hover");

    $("#home").removeClass("hover");
    $("#homepages").removeClass("hover");
    $("#apps").removeClass("hover");
    $("#facebook").removeClass("hover");
    $("#kontakt").removeClass("hover");

    $("#content").hide();
});​
```

Comment: I think he still wants to do the other stuff in the function though.

Comment: It isn't returning out of the function.  The current function executing will still run.  But the event will be unbound so it will not happen again.

Comment: Yes, but when the user hovers again, nothing will happen. I think the OP wants that everything else still happens again (for example addClass("hover")), just not the load.

Answer (score 0):

Update a data attribute on `#content` that contains the url or id of the currently loaded content. Also, you should handle the case where the user hovers over a different section before the previous is done loading.

```
var request; // use this same var for all, don't re-declare it
$("#blogs").mouseover(function () {

    // exit event if the blog is the current content in #content
    if ( $("#content").data("current") == "blog") return;

    $("#content").data("current","blog");
    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $("#home").removeClass("hover");
    $("#homepages").removeClass("hover");
    $("#apps").removeClass("hover");
    $("#facebook").removeClass("hover");
    $("#kontakt").removeClass("hover");

    // if a previous request is still pending, abort it
    if ($.isFunction(request.abort) && request.state() == "pending") request.abort();

    // request content
    request = $.get("blogs.html");
    $("#content").hide();

    // when content is done loading, update #content element
    request.done(function(result){
        $("#content").html(result); 
    });
});
```

I strongly suggest against using hover for loading content with ajax.

Also, in it's current form, this code is not very re-usable, you'll have to have one for each link. I suggest instead using classes and having only one event binding handling all of the links.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) to detect descendants of content

```
$("#blogs").mouseover(
    function () {
      $(this).addClass("hover");    
      $("#home,#homepages,#apps,#facebook,#kontakt").removeClass("hover");
      var $c = $("#content");
      if($c.has('.check_blog')){ // if content contains an element with that class
          $("#content").hide().load("blogs.html", function(){
          $("#content").show("slide"); 
      }

    });  
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
$("#blogs").mouseover(
 function () {
   $(this).addClass("hover");

   $("#home").removeClass("hover");
   $("#homepages").removeClass("hover");
   $("#apps").removeClass("hover");
   $("#facebook").removeClass("hover");
   $("#kontakt").removeClass("hover");

   if($('#content').html() == '') {
    $("#content").hide().load("blogs.html", function(){
     $("#content").show("slide"); 
    });  
   }
});
```